# MYSQL Query not extract my expected output

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a two tables in MySQL database:

- **vehicle**
- **vehicle logs**

When the user inserts a vehicle into the system, the vehicle logs table also generates a new 'vehicle added' row. When something happens to the vehicle, the log table also updates accordingly. Below are the vehicle and vehicle logs tables:

Vehicle Table

```
CREATE TABLE `asset_vehicle` (
  `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `asset_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `engine_capacity` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `engine_no` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `no_of_doors` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Vehicle Logs Table

```
CREATE TABLE `asset_vehicle_logs` (
  `id_pk` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `date_log` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_log` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_pk`),
  KEY `FK7up0y9054d64e3mvue3r4pe9e` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

'id' acts as primary key for the Vehicle Table and as foreign key for the vehicle logs table.

This is an issue. The logs table maintains several statuses for vehicles. I want to filter based on the 'date_log' column, to keep recent states only. when one status is selected, the query should return the relevant vehicle. One vehicle should not have different statuses in the same data range.

I wrote a query to perform this. But it returns the same vehicles in other reports.

Query 1

```
select * from asset_vehicle_logs l join asset_vehicle v on l.id = v.id where l.description = 'Vehicle verified' and  l.date_log between '2023-12-01' and '2023-12-31' group by l.id  order by l.date_log desc,l.time_log desc;
```

Query 2

```
select * from asset_vehicle_logs l join asset_vehicle v on l.id = v.id where l.description = 'Vehicle rejected' and  l.date_log between '2023-12-01' and '2023-12-31' group by l.id  order by l.date_log desc,l.time_log desc;
```

Updates

Vehicle Table sample data
[image]

Vehicle logs table sample data filtered based on the ID of the vehicle table.

sample logs table 1(filter by ID)
[image]

sample logs table 2(filter by ID)
[image]

sample logs table 3(filter by ID)
[image]

Comment: There aren't any foreign keys in the published code.

Comment: Please add sample data and desired outcome as text.

Comment: Dear  P.Salmon, I edited my post and add sample data for refer.

Comment: We can't use images for best results post text..

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid but we would need a sample of the data set. If you can create a minimal dataset that can be used to reproduce your problem, please do that.

The queries should return vehicles that has entries in the log table with `description = 'Vehicle rejected'` and `description = 'Vehicle verified'`.

The problem is, in the database structure that you presented there is no mechanism to make sure there is only one entry in the log table per vehicle ID. Are you 100% it is unique?

What about adding UNIQUE key on `'id' varchar(40) NOT NULL` in the `asset_vehicle_logs` table? That would ensure there’s only one entry in the logs for the single vehicle.

Comment: I update my post and add some sample data for refer. In the second picture of the logs table it mentioned both 'vehicle approved' and 'vehicle rejected' states. I wan't to filter latest state only from above states. How can I do that? When consider the 'id' column it is unique and updated as a UUID. Not the auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship between vehicle and vehicle_logs is one-to-many, nothing prevents a log from being created several times for the same vehicle, on the same day, in the vehicle_logs table. If you want each vehicle to only have one log at a time, you need to invert the relationship and move your foreign key to the vehicle table.

Also, for clarity, I would rename 'id' and 'id_pk' in your vehicle_logs table:

`` CREATE TABLE `asset_vehicle_logs` ( `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `description` varchar(2000) NOT NULL, `id_vehicle` varchar(40) NOT NULL, `date_log` date DEFAULT NULL, `time_log` time DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY `FK7up0y9054d64e3mvue3r4pe9e` (`id_vehicle`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4; ``

UPDATE: You explained that it is fine to have several logs for one given vehicle in the same day, what you want is to get the latest one. In this case, I would add LIMIT 1 to your original queries.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I wan't a Query for extract the recent state from the log table. In the same day can move to diffent states.

Comment: So, to make sure I understand: There can be multiple entries for the same vehicle in the same day in the vehicle-logs table, but you need to retrieve the most recent entry for a given vehicle is that correct? For example, there would be 3 logs for Toyota 00018b-c15 on 19/03/2024, one in the morning, one in the afternoon and one in the evening. And you need to get the evening one?

Comment: Yes, I wan't to get evening one. Others should be rejected.

Comment: That's a "groupwise max" problem.